# how do i keep data once out of block code?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-3

I'm trying to parse a JSON link using AFNetworking and MJExtensions.
see comments in code.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      NSString *apiURL = @"https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/Lat,Long";

      NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:apiURL];

      AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
      [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
          weatherDict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
          weather = [WeatherClasses mj_objectWithKeyValues:weatherDict];


          //----------------------
          //when i set the label.text here, the label shows whatever the JSON value is
          self.apparentTemperature.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", weather.currently.apparentTemperature];
          NSLog(@"Temp: %f", weather.currently.apparentTemperature);

      } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
      //--------------------------
      //but if i set the label here, its always 0 (or nil for NSString)
      self.apparentTemperature.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", weather.currently.apparentTemperature];
  }
```

while in the success block, my dictionary has data, but when i get out the success block, the dictionary is nil. how can i make it so that the dictionary isn't nil once its set in AFHTTPSessionManager?

using __block didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `//but if i set the label here, its always 0 (or nil for NSString)`

That's because that code runs *before* the network request completes, so the data doesn't exist. When you pass a block into an asynchronous method like a network call, the block will usually execute *after* the method in which you made the call has exited.

> using __block didn't work.

Not surprising. `__block` ensures that a variable so marked is used itself inside the block rather than duplicated in the block's context, but it won't make the data come back any faster.

The right solution here is to set your label in the completion block for the request -- that's the sort of thing that completion blocks are *for*.

> how do i keep data once out of block code?

Don't try -- there's no reason not to set the variable inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are asynchronous, which means that `self.apparentTemperature.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", weather.currently.apparentTemperature];` will probably be executed before the block, where `weather` is set.

That is the reason why `self.apparentTemperature.text` is always `nil` outside of the block.

To overcome this issue, just call a function where you set your UI elements at the end of your block (but within the block), this way it will be called after the block has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use __block keyword when you decalre weatherDict out of block code.

Comment: i used `@interface ViewController () {
    __block WeatherClasses *weather;
    __block NSDictionary *weatherDict;
}
@end
` and it the label still shows 0

Comment: this is in viewcontroller.m

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a semaphore:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
   ...

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
self.apparentTemperature.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", weather.currently.apparentTemperature];
```

But I don't think that's the case. As people have said the correct way to do it is asynchronously.

Simply put your code to set the label that's after the block or simply don't include it at all. The only purpose of this code is to set the default value while your block isn't called.

As soon as you have a response from the server your block will be called and you should place your logic inside it, as it is right now.